# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'float'

Tags: python

I am receiving this error

---

TypeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-995aa3052f74> in <module>()
      A,B,C,D = 200, 48.475, 0.0026, 400
--->  y_true = sigmoide(x, A, B, C, D)
<ipython-input-7-995aa3052f74> in sigmoide(x, A, B, C, D)
          """4PL sigmoide equation."""
--->      return A*erf((x-B)/C*sqrt(2)) + D
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: '_io.TextIOWrapper' and 'float'
```

when I am trying to run this Code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
def sigmoide(x, A, B, C, D):
    """4PL sigmoide equation."""
    return A*erf((x-B)/C*sqrt(2)) + D

def residuals(p, y, x):
    """Deviations of data from fitted 4PL curve"""
    A,B,C,D = p
    err = y-sigmoide(x, A, B, C, D)
    return err

def peval(x, p):
    """Evaluated value at x with current parameters."""
    A,B,C,D = p
    return sigmoide(x, A, B, C, D)

# Make up some data for fitting and add noise
# In practice, y_meas would be read in from a file
x = open("C:\\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\data\data1.txt", "r")
A,B,C,D = 200, 48.475, 0.0026, 400
y_true = sigmoide(x, A, B, C, D)
y_meas = open("C:\\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\data\data2.txt", "r")

# Initial guess for Parameters
p0 = [0, 100, 100, 100]

# Fit equation using least squares optimization
plsq = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(y_meas, x))

# Plot results
plt.plot(x,peval(x,plsq[0]),x,y_meas,'o',x,y_true)
plt.title('Least-squares 4PL fit to noisy data')
plt.legend(['Fit', 'Noisy', 'True'], loc='upper left')
for i, (param, actual, est) in enumerate(zip('ABCD', [A,B,C,D], plsq[0])):
    plt.text(10, 3-i*0.5, '%s = %.2f, est(%s) = %.2f' % (param, actual, param, est))
plt.savefig('sigmoide.png')
```

Please any help for solving this error?Thanks!

Comment: In order for somebody to help you - you need to provide minimal reproducible example. Files you are opening in script are preventing this, and based on your error most probably `x` is getting string value from that file instead float sigmoide function is expecting... Can you give minimal example, substituting the x and y_meas values with some relevant example of data (random is also fine as long it is reproducible error)?

Comment: @Const `open` doesn't return a string.

Comment: @Josh, yes, completely right about that part! Still, original argument stands it is used in equation later on and also preventing minimal example...

Answer (score 1):

you define `x` as being an open file:

```
x = open("C:\\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\data\data1.txt", "r")
```

But instead of reading data from the file, you're calling the `sigmoide` function and passing the open file as first parameter!

```
y_true = sigmoide(x, A, B, C, D)
```

Inside the function, you proceed to try to calculate a subtraction from an open file!

```
return A*erf((x-B)/C*sqrt(2)) + D
```

That of course won't work - Python doesn't know how to subtract a number from an open file! Then you get `unsupported operand type(s)` error.

Comment: Whereas in C, this would be a valid operation and probably quite a nasty (if not immediately apparent) bug to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all of you!

@Const: as you mentioned the error is due to that the x and y_meas files are in script instead of float when I open them. Here is the Code through which I solved the error:

```
x = open("C:\\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\data\data1.txt", "r")

f1=np.array(x.read().split("\n")).astype(float)

print(f1)


y_meas = open("C:\\Users\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\data\data2.txt", "r")

f2=np.array(y_meas.read().split("\n")).astype(float)

print(f2)
```